# What is the most acceptable way to let a visitor know they are on an unsupoorted browser?

Tags: use-case

I'm developing a site that uses JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3 heavily. I have no desire to support last generations browsers (IE8 and under for example.) What is the most acceptable way to let the visitor know they are on an old browser?

Redirect to a place letting them know? Should I let them in anyway after I let them know even though a large portion of the site wont work? Should I recommend a browser to use, or list all functional browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not suggested to allow users to use your page if you are confident that the experience will be a disaster. If you know that 80% of the page won't work, you should advice your users to change the browser or don't use the page at all. If you don't do it, your credibility could be affected...a user could think the page is broken, or not professional.

The best way is to redirect to a page explaining the problem and suggesting A LIST of possible browsers, never a single one. If you suggest a single one, you could be seen as propaganda of this browser.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You're on a dangerous road trying to come up with a "list of functional browsers". I'd strongly reconsider that entire approach if I were you. There are [so many great ways](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) to support "older" browsers. It's not nearly as hard as it used to be.

Start by reading: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/understandingprogressiveenhancement/

Then look into using jQuery, Modernizr, and similar tools to help with your cross-browser/cross version woes.

Comment: I'm already using jQuery, but rounded borders and transitions don't seem to be backwards compatible as far as I can tell. I'm going to be using the canvas and or SVG quite a bit for animation as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a user, nothing is more irritating than being shut out of something because my browser has been rejected.

I would suggest notifying the visitor that their browser is unlikely to deliver a satisfying experience on your site (and explain that you are using the latest standards).  Provide links to perhaps three acceptable browsers.  Then *let them in anyway*.  You never know when someone may show up with something that works but wasn't on your list of approved browsers.

Ideally, have your site degrade gracefully in older browsers by writing semantically-correct HTML that still renders even if some of the CSS and HTML features you're using are not supported.